# Resistor in between two meshes

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: Simulation of the circuit]

I apologize if a similar question to this have already been asked.

I am trying to find the voltage between points A and B.

I wanted to ask why is there no current flowing through the middle 2-ohm resistor?

<s>And why does it have a voltage of 2.67 volts? From my understanding, it seems to have been based on the voltage drops on the right mesh. Why is that? Couldn't it have been based from the left mesh? The voltage between A and B seems to be 1.3333 volts either way.</s> I just realized that I had put the ground on that side. So it may be the reason why, isn't it?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Ground is defined as "0" volts. If you cunningly hide the ground off screen, as you have, we have to guess what is on the other end of the wire.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon It's just the ground on that wire, nothing else. I cropped it off from the screenshot just to show the circuit better.

Comment: NB - this is a comment - NOT a criticism. Re Ground - we guessed that BUT you neither showed it or told us.  Having a "magic wire" disappearing off screen is unlikely to ever be useful. Just adding a ground symbol somewhere along the right hand base line makes the "probably the case" certain. The 0V is a fair 'giveaway' as otherwise the diagram is totally reference free and could equally be floating at 10V or a million.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no current flowing because there's no loop. Current has to flow in a closed loop, so no current *can* flow through that resistor.

The voltage being the same on both sides is because of ohm's law; with no current through a resistor, both sides must be at the same voltage. You'll notice that, to make this work, the negative terminal of the left voltage source is now at -1.33 V relative to ground.

Comment: I see. I was working under the assumption that the current would divide at nodes C and D (left and right nodes of the middle 2-ohm resistor). So, I guess it wouldn't do that because there is no loop to go back to the negative terminal?

Comment: @MarkJohnson Right. Conservation of charge, and all that.

Comment: Last: If I followed the voltage drops of the left mesh and set the voltages of both sides of the middle resistor to 4V, would that be acceptable? (Do note that I just put the ground on the right mesh for the simulation to work)

Comment: @MarkJohnson No loop, no flow. Having the voltages the same is "coincidence". IF you connected a ground connection to a node on either side then there would be an implicit connection between them (ground is an ideal piece of wire that you define as being at 0.000...volts), but otherwise, no.

Comment: @MarkJohnson No, not without moving your ground. Otherwise setting both sides to +4 V would be changing the circuit.